# Let $g(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-4}$ Is $g(x)$ continuous at $x_0=4$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $g(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-4}$
Is $g(x)$ continous at $x_0=4$?

So first of all i wanted to ask. Why does this question make sense at all ? $x_0=4$ is not in the domain of $g(x)$ so asking about continuity makes no sense to me at this point?

Anyways $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$ goes to infinity. So i assume its not continuous. 
Can i follow this using the epsilon delta definition of continuity ? 
Or is anything that goes to infinity directly not continuous ?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not since it is not defined at $4$.

Comment: Ok  what about $\frac {x^2-1}{x+1}$ Is it continous at x=-1?

Comment: Again, it is not for the same reason, but you can extend it to a continuos function.

Comment: Why is my book asking this question then ? I dont understand. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

g(x) is not defined at x=4 as the denominator is 0, therefore it cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on this a little bit. In most textbooks, they often have the function: $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-16}{x-4}$ and $x = 4$ is the removable discontinuity as you know since the limit does not exist there. You can make the function continuous at $x = 4$ by define $f(4) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 4} f(x) = 8$. I hope this explanation gives you more insight into the question you are having.

Comment: But i dont understand the point of it ? Why ask such a question ? Wouldnt asking something like can you make the function continuous better  ?